# getting the type of element from array C

Tags: c

I was wondering if it is possible in C to get the type from an element in an array. I have the following code, where you have to manually specify the type, but would like to remove the second argument.

```
#define ForEach( func, type, list)do {\
    int num_elements = sizeof(list) / sizeof(type);\
    int iter;\
    for( iter = 0; iter < num_elements; iter++)\
        func(list[iter]);\
    }while(0)

void display(int n) {
    printf("\n%d\n", n);
}

int main(void){
    int list [] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ForEach(display, int, list);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of this question - You can use `sizeof` operator on elements of the array as -

```
sizeof(list[0])
```

If you are using GCC (or anything GNU), there is an extenstion called `typeof`. You can do

```
sizeof(typeof(list[0]))
```

But the C way of doing it is directly use `sizeof` the element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. What you can do is instead of

```
sizeof(type)
```

do

```
sizeof(list[0])
```

But this may not work for malloced arrays.

[Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: Why exactly won't this work with `malloc`'d arrays? As long as you use the correct type for the pointer, it should work.

Comment: There is a huge difference between size of an array and size of an element. Here we are doing size of the element. It will work even on malloc'd arrays.